# ScoreNinja titleText and subboard are not doing anything

Tags: android, scoreninja

I am using ScoreNinja (a high score manager) in my android game, and I want to use the subboard feature mentioned in the documentation.

But when I do this:

```
mScoreNinjaAdapter.show(score, "Test Title", "test_board");
```

It doesn't do anything differently. The title is still "Global High Scores" and it is still showing scores from the main board.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this in an aSync thread (as I suspect you are since it's communicating by network), make sure you're using activity.runOnUiThread.

This allows you to make UI changes in other threads.  This is necessary because the UI is not threadsafe.

Check out [this article](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) and see if it helps you with your problem.

Hope this helps!